# XSLT Xml output is stripping whitespace from closing slash

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlstarlet

The XSLT XML output format is stripping the whitespace before the closing tag

`<Import Include="System.Web" />` becomes `<Import Include="System.Web"/>`

As the XSLT is also removing many nodes in the documents it's applied to, I would like to strip whitespace except in the case of the closing slash.

The xslt is being applied to many xml ms proj files

template.xsl;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!--<xsl:preserve-space elements="text"/>-->

    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    ... 
    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is a serialization detail that is impossible to control from XSLT. The only reliable way to achieve it is to run a post-processor on the result of the transformation.

Comment: Also note that `<a/>` and `<a />` are exactly the same thing, as far as XML is concerned. Quirky parsers that erroneously see a difference notwithstanding. That doesn't really have anything to do with `xsl:strip-space`.

Comment: Could you explain why you have this requirement? Is there a consumer of the XML that cares about the difference? If so, it's non-conformant - but it would still be nice to know about it.

Comment: proj files generated by VS have the space in all the imports/file refs, running this XSLT over hundreds of projects generated a significant amount of unnecessary source changes - possibly may cause reformatting when adding/removing more files in the future

Answer (score 3):

**This is a serialization detail that is impossible to control from XSLT**.

Any reliable way to achieve it would be to run a post-processor on the result of the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using gnuwin32 sed to add a space (note the `^>` : `^` is required to escape the angled bracket)

```
sed\sed.exe -i "s/\"\/^>/\" \/>/g" %outfile%
```